# React treats "{variable}" syntax as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Backdrop.css';

const Backdrop = props => {
  const bd = props.show ? <div className={styles.Backdrop} onClick={props.clicked} /> : null
  return (
    {bd}
  );
};

export default Backdrop;
```

And I get this error message

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {bd}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, especially since I've used this syntax before and everything was ok. I know that I don't have to use a variable to display this but final version of this component requires using that part of code as a variable. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Wouldn't `return bd` work?

Comment: In ES6+, `{ bd }` is shorthand for `{ bd: bd }`

Answer (score 4):

You only need {} curly braces in a JSX element. In a return statement just return the variable.

```
const Backdrop = props => {
  const bd = props.show ? <div className={styles.Backdrop} onClick={props.clicked} /> : null
  return (
    bd
  );
};
```

compared to :

```
const Backdrop = props => {
  const bd = props.show ? <div className={styles.Backdrop} onClick={props.clicked} /> : null
  return (
    // In a <h1> tag, you use curly braces
    <h1>{bd}</h1>
  );
};
```

Comment: Note that if you do {bd}, it will get converted to this object: `{bd: *value of bd*}`

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement does not need the curly braces. Those are needed only inside jsx expressions.
The return is after the end of a jsx expression.